# Rails form builder without form tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I need to replace part of form by js.
Can i use form builder to render my partials without

```
<form> </form>
```

tags?

Something like this:

```
  =simple_nested_form_for @object, skip_form_tag: true do |f|
    = render partial: 'partial', locals: {f: f}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fields_for` instead - that might do what you're looking for:

```
= fields_for(@object) do |your_object|
  = render partial: 'partial', locals: {f: your_object}
```